# using accept: in jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am using jquery drag-and-drop and I have 3 divs.

I want the gallery div to accept li from other two divs. I am using:

```
$gallery.droppable({
accept: '#DIV1 li',
```

I cannot figure out how to put two div1 li and div2 li in accept:

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accept option takes a selector so just use a comma-separated list.

```
$gallery.droppable( { accept: '#DIV1 li, #DIV2 li', ...
```